# Grep from a file and store the result lines in separate file, and the file name should increment with every entry

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a shell script which will get an input from a column in csv file line by line and that input is used to search in another file.
The line(s) in which the resulting pattern is found should be stored in another file. And with every such iteration, the file name should also increment.
For example, test1, test2, test3,...

Below is the code i used:

```
#!/bin/bash


input=file1.csv

while
IFS=,
read -a csv_line;
do echo "${csv_line[1]}";
for((i=0;i<=22558;i++))
do
#echo "${csv_line[1]}";
filename=$'test'${i++};
grep "csv_line[1]" log_file > filename.txt;
echo=$filename;
echo="$csv_line[1]}"
done<file1.csv
done
```

I did not get any error, but when i execute the script, it neither shows anything nor it gets stored in file. Using my code, the filename does not change to test1. but remains as "filename.txt"

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Thankyou for referring the site.
    I made the changes.
    
    #!/bin/bash
    
    while
            IFS=,
            read -r csv_line;
    do echo "${csv_line[1]}";
    
    for((i=0;i<=22558;i++))
    do
        #echo "${csv_line[1]}";
        filename=$'test'${i++};
        grep "csv_line[1]" RBFCDC_in.log.2015-11-23.PROD > filename.txt;
        #echo=$filename;
    
    done<dbo_fidessa_order_hist_sql.csv
    
    done

I still get an error for naming filename. Please advice.

Comment: You can (and should) [edit] your question to add that.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need?

```
#!/bin/bash 

counter=0
while read -r csv_line
do 
    value=$(cut -d ',' -f2 <<< $csv_line)
    counter=$((counter+1))
    grep $value RBFCDC_in.log.2015-11-23.PROD > "test$counter"; 
done < dbo_fidessa_order_hist_sql.csv
```